# Binary Search Using a While Loop (Infinite)

Tags: loops, search, while-loop, binary

I have to implement a Binary Search method using a loop (while). For some weird reason (well, weird for me) the loop keeps going on infinitely, even though certain conditions are met to exit the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void Bin_search(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList, int targetValue)
{
  int totalCount = 0;
  int low = 0;
  int high = arrayList.size();
  while (low <= high)
  {
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if(targetValue < arrayList.get(mid))
      high = mid - 1;
    else if(targetValue > arrayList.get(mid))
      low = mid + 1;
    else
      totalCount++;
  }
  System.out.println("Number of times "+targetValue+" appears: "+totalCount+" time(s).");
}
```

Comment: What did the debugger say? What conditions are not handled correctly?

Comment: Well the debugger doesn't say anything - everything compiles fine, but the moment I run it, pass the parameters and call the method, the programs gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: And that's when you step it through step by step with the debugger to see what's wrong.

Comment: Okay. So I tried rewriting the code and this time I used a return statement instead of void. It worked - oddly. Could this have something to do with `totalCount`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your algorithm.  The binary search I'm pretty sure assumes the list is both unique and in order, and returns/escapes the loop when the value is found or iterated through the list by changing the min/max value. In your final else, where the value is found, all it does is increment the counter and it never returns (where a normal binary search would escape the loop), nor does it update the min or max values so your guess will always be the same in future loops. It'll always find it and it'll always increment but never escape, which is why it's an infinite loop if the value is found, but it will escape the loop if the value is not found.